# Interface with generic method iterating over enum values in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, enums, interface

Assuming these interfaces

```
interface RatingValue {
    val value: Int
}

interface RatingValues {
    fun ratings() : List<Int>
    fun cumulativeRating() : Int = ratings().sum()
}
```

And a bunch of enums similar to this one

```
enum class MarkFoo(override val value: Int) : RatingValue {
        EXCELENT(5),
        VERY_GOOD(4),
        GOOD(3),
        FAIR(2),
        POOR(1);

        companion object : RatingValues {
            override fun ratings() = values().map(MarkFoo::value)
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to generically extract the implementation of ratings() function into RatingValues interface in order to avoid having basically the same exact implementation in companions of all enumerations? Each of the enums will implement RatingValue and each will have a companion implementing RatingValues

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t think so. `values()` is not part of the Enum interface, and you can’t create an extension function that uses companion objects as receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generify `RatingValues` interface to access methods of `Enum<T>` and `RatingValue` from it.
But since reified generics are not allowed for interfaces and even for their virtual members, you'll have to convert these methods into extensions:

```kotlin
interface RatingValues<T>
inline fun <reified T> RatingValues<T>.ratings(): List<Int> where T : RatingValue, T : Enum<T> = enumValues<T>().map { it.value }
inline fun <reified T> RatingValues<T>.cumulativeRating(): Int where T : RatingValue, T : Enum<T> = ratings().sum()
```

Usage:

```kotlin
enum class MarkFoo(override val value: Int) : RatingValue {
    EXCELENT(5),
    VERY_GOOD(4),
    GOOD(3),
    FAIR(2),
    POOR(1);

    companion object : RatingValues<MarkFoo>
}
```

The problem is these methods cannot be also declared as abstract interface members, because in this case extensions would be shadowed. So they can now be called on this interface only for specific `T`s (enums, implementing `RatingValue` interface) and cannot be overriden. For other types interface would be empty, without any methods to override:

```
class X(override val value: Int) : RatingValue
class XX : RatingValues<X> {
    override fun ratings(): List<Int> { /*...*/ } //Impossible now
    override fun cumulativeRating(): Int { /*...*/ } //Impossible now
}

val res = XX.ratings() // Will not compile now since X is not enum
```

If you intend to use this interface in aforementioned way too, then you'll have to declare interface as before, add only one extension but with different name (like `ratingsForEnums`) and add some boilerpate each time you implement this interface for enums:

```kotlin
interface RatingValues<T> {
    fun ratings(): List<Int>
    fun cumulativeRating(): Int = ratings().sum()
}

inline fun <reified T> RatingValues<T>.ratingsForEnums(): List<Int> where T : RatingValue, T : Enum<T> = enumValues<T>().map { it.value }

enum class MarkFoo(override val value: Int) : RatingValue {
    EXCELENT(5),
    VERY_GOOD(4),
    GOOD(3),
    FAIR(2),
    POOR(1);

    companion object : RatingValues<MarkFoo> {
        override fun ratings() = ratingsForEnums()
    }
}
```

If you're going to use this interface in contrast only with enums, then it make sense to impose limitations for `T` explicitly on an interface level as well:

```kotlin
interface RatingValues<T> where T : RatingValue, T : Enum<T>
```